# Ruby on Rails inheritance with new attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I've been searching about ruby on rails inheritance but all I could find is inheritance where there's no new attributes, like this:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Dog < Animal; end
class Cat < Animal; end
```

and adding a new type field to the table

```
class CreateAnimals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :animals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :race
      t.string :type
    end
  end
end
```

But how do I add a new attribute to Dog, for instance? 
like, Dogs have a 'name' and a 'race' inherited from Animal, but how do I add 'bark_type', that only a Dog have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Single-table inheritance (STI). Basically you have a single table in the database called Pets which has all the required attributes (including ones for subclasses) and you have a "type" column which should be no-null and its the column you store the sub-class e.g "dog"

there is a fine example that has a Pet, dogs and cats example [here](https://kconrails.com/2010/01/26/single-table-inheritance-with-tests-in-ruby-on-rails/)

example

DogsController < ApplicationController

```
   def new
    @dog = Dog.new
   end

   def create
    @dog = Dog.new(dog_params)
    if @dog.save
     ...
    end
   end

private 

  def dog_params
    params.require(:dog).permit(:name, :age)
  end
end
```

Important

By calling `Dog.new` instead of `Pet.new` is like saying to activerecord this is a new record for the Pet table and in the column called "type" add the string "dog"

Note 2: If for cats model you do not want to save :age parameter, you just don't have an age field in your form. BUT because for dogs you also want the age, the Pets table should have an age column that will be used by the Dog model

Comment: yep, it's STI, i'm just not sure about how doing it on rails. I would have one controller for dog and one for cat that saves on the pets table? how would I do that? the example you linked doesn't have any new attributes on the cat/dog classes

Comment: Please read the link i provided carefully. as i said, all attributes of either cat or dog need to be columns on the pet table. The type column of the Pet table will have the subclass e.g "dog". I will update my answer with a small example